# What is the meaning of Volume factor?

Tags: calculation, terminology

I want to calculate T3 Moving Average. In order to calculate T3 Moving Average, it need Volume factor, But I don't know Volume factor.

What is the meaning of Volume factor as a terminology of investment and How I can calculate?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info at https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/x-study/technical-indicator-definitions/t3-t3/,

> vFactor  is a volume factor between 0 and 1 which determines how the
>   moving  averages responds. A value of 0 returns an EMA. A value of 1
>   returns  DEMA. Tim Tillson advised or preferred a value of 0.7.